# Jquery UI generated on the fly is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some Jquery UI sliders with different data-id.
How is it possible to detect who is the selected and return the sliders value in a span next to it?

I am generate the sliders and the other elements dynamicaly:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
value:100,
min: 0,
max: 50000,
step: 50,
create: function () {
    $(this).slider( "option", "value", $(this).next().val() );
},
slide: function( event, ui ) {                 
     //get the id of this slider
var id = $(this).data('id');
     //select the input box that has the same id as the slider within it and set it's value to the current slider value. 
$("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
//$("div[class*=" + id + "]").val(ui.value);
}
});
});
</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#adding").click(function() {

var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" value=\"Enter your Facebook fan page url\" />");
var fType = $("<div id=\"slider\" datta-id=\"slider" + intId + "\" style='width:250px; float:left; margin-left:10px;'></div>").slider();
var fLikes= $("<span class=\"slider" + intId + "\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 24px; float: left; margin-left: 13px; margin-top: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; color: rgb(243, 20, 145); text-align: center; font-family: serif;\" />");
var fCost = $("<div class=\"fieldname\" id=\"fcost" + intId + "\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 24px; float: left; margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; color: rgb(243, 20, 145); text-align: center; font-family: serif;\" />");
var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
removeButton.click(function() {
$(this).parent().remove();
});
fieldWrapper.append(fName);
fieldWrapper.append(fType);
fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
fieldWrapper.append(fLikes);
fieldWrapper.append(fCost);
$("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
});
</script>

And inside the body:

<fieldset id="buildyourform">
<legend>Welcome! <span style="color:#F00; margin-left:13px;">My products</span></legend>
</fieldset>

<div id="adding"></div>
```

Comment: You misspelled `data-id` as `datta-id`.

Comment: You're giving all the DIVs the same `id="slider"`. Duplicate IDs are not allowed.

Comment: Instead of using `data-id`, use `$(this).next()`, since the `fType` span is right after the `fName` DIV.

Comment: Tried without luck... any jsfiddle example guys?

Comment: If you make the jsfiddle, I'll look at it.

Comment: @IreneT. Make a jsfiddle with your code and post it here. It is unlikely you will get help without posting the fiddle.

Comment: Here guys is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/

Comment: @Barmar i posted my jsfiddle!

Comment: The Newest jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, For doing this you could make a global variable that store the common properties of all the slider as :

```
slider_options =
{
  value:100,
  min: 0,
  max: 50000,
  step: 50,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  create: function( e, ui ) {
    //was throwing TypeError: closestHandle is undefined with you previous code so i changed it to  
    var bar=$(this).slider('value');
 },
  slide: function( event, ui ) { 
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
   },
};
```

And now it is set you can use it in your `slider()` initialization code as :

```
var fType = $("<div id=\"slider\" data-id=\"slider" + intId + "\" style='width:250px; float:left; margin-left:10px;'></div>").slider(slider_options);
```

After which you can get the desired `data-id` on the `slide` event of the slider.

### And here is the [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/8/)

Comment: Great job... many many thanks.. i have one more question..
In the div next to span how can i display the slider value * 0.10?

Comment: i have updated the fiddle check it out http://jsfiddle.net/Yg85V/9/. And glad it worked out for you.